# jQuery attribute selector inside a jQuery object

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-filter

I'm trying to set up a quicksand with multiple filters and the approach I'm taking in the following which I'm not sure if it's the best.

```
$filteredItems = $containerClone.find('.portfolio-item-marketing').filter(function(index){

            if ( $filterA != 'all' && $filterB != 'all' )
            {
                return jQuery(this).find('.portfolio-item-marketing[data-type~=' + $filterA + ']') || jQuery(this).find('.portfolio-item-marketing[data-type~=' + $filterB + ']');
            }

            if ( $filterA != 'all' && $filterB == 'all' )
            {
                return jQuery(this+'[data-type~='+$filterA+']')  ;
            }

            if ( $filterA == 'all' && $filterB != 'all' )
            {
                return  jQuery(this).find('.portfolio-item-marketing[data-type~=' + $filterB + ']');
            }

            if ( $filterA == 'all' && $filterB == 'all' )
            {
                return jQuery(this).find('.portfolio-item-marketing');
            }

        });
```

As you see in the code I tried 2 different methods ( First "if" and second "if" ). I'm not sure if I can use find inside a filter but i also dont know how to get the attribute from the jQuery object.

I can not use

```
jQuery(this).attr('data-type') == $filterA
```

Because the attribute maybe contain various filters. That's why I'm trying to use jQuery "~="

Should I give up and end using a indexOf ?

HTML markup for example:

```
<ul class="filterA filters">
    <li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="all">All</a></li>  
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="digital-books">Digital Books</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="pdf">Pdf</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="filterB filters">
    <li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="all">All</a></li>  
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="3m">3M</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="mcdonald">Mc Donald</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="sony">Sony</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="portfolio-wrap" class="clearfix">
    <div class="portfolio-item-marketing" data-id="1" data-type="digital-books 3m "></div>
    <div class="portfolio-item-marketing" data-id="1" data-type="pdf 3m "></div>
    <div class="portfolio-item-marketing" data-id="1" data-type="digital-books sony "></div>
    <div class="portfolio-item-marketing" data-id="1" data-type="pdf mcdonald "></div>
</div>
```

Quicksand Filter script :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if(jQuery().quicksand) {

    portfolio_quicksand();

    }

});

function portfolio_quicksand() {

    // Setting up our variables
    var $filter;
    var $container;
    var $containerClone;
    var $filterLink;
    var $filteredItems

    // Set our filter
    $filterA = jQuery('.filterA li.active a').attr('class');

    $filterB = jQuery('.filterB li.active a').attr('class');

    // Set our filter link
    $filterLink = jQuery('.filters li a');

    // Set our container
    $container = jQuery('#portfolio-wrap');

    // Clone our container
    $containerClone = $container.clone();

    // Apply our Quicksand to work on a click function
    // for each of the filter li link elements
    $filterLink.click(function(e)
    {

        // Remove the active class
        jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('li').removeClass('active');

        // Apply the 'active' class to the clicked link
        jQuery(this).parent().addClass('active');


        // Set our filter
        $filterA = jQuery('.filterA li.active a').attr('class');

        $filterB = jQuery('.filterB li.active a').attr('class');

        $filteredItems = $containerClone.find('.portfolio-item-marketing').filter(function(index){

            if ( $filterA != 'all' && $filterB != 'all' )
            {
                return jQuery(this).find('.portfolio-item-marketing[data-type~=' + $filterA + ']') || jQuery(this).find('.portfolio-item-marketing[data-type~=' + $filterB + ']');
            }

            if ( $filterA != 'all' && $filterB == 'all' )
            {
                return jQuery(this+'[data-type~='+$filterA+']')  ;
            }

            if ( $filterA == 'all' && $filterB != 'all' )
            {
                return  jQuery(this).find('.portfolio-item-marketing[data-type~=' + $filterB + ']');
            }

            if ( $filterA == 'all' && $filterB == 'all' )
            {
                return jQuery(this).find('.portfolio-item-marketing');
            }

        });



        // Finally call the Quicksand function
        $container.quicksand($filteredItems,
        {
            // The duration for the animation
            duration: 750,
            // The easing effect when animating
            easing: 'easeInOutCirc',
            // Height adjustment set to dynamic
            adjustHeight: 'dynamic'
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Show your mark-up, or a representative sample; I think this could be done more easily/succinctly, but I don't know what your filters are, or where they're coming from.

Comment: What is this code doing? I can't understand a thing, I would try to rename those variables with something meaningful. Such unorganized code with all that noise makes it really hard to read; I've to scroll left and right! Also, have you heard about DRY and `switch`?